# Is Ikea required by Russian law to pay employees for the next 3 months, despite suspending all operations (sales, production) in Russia?

Tags: employment, russia

Ikea [announced](https://www.reuters.com/business/ikea-temporarily-closes-its-stores-russia-halts-sourcing-russia-belarus-2022-03-03/) they'll still be paying their 15,000 Russian employees their salaries for the next 3 months, even though they've suspended all operations in Russia, sales and production (17 stores and 3 factories).

I'm curious if them still paying employees for the next 3 months is required by Russian law, or if Ikea went over and above that requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [legal requirement in Russia](https://uk.practicallaw.thomsonreuters.com/5-503-4083?transitionType=Default&contextData=(sc.Default)#co_anchor_a202414) is to pay or to continue to employ workers for two months following the notice of a layoff.

The three month period was probably chosen to put to rest questions about how to treat a mid-month announcement and any questions over the effective date of the notice which may have post-dated the *de facto* shutdown of operations.